# How to post a .swf on Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, fbsdk

I am trying to post a `.swf` using PHP SDK 5.2. I have tried a few methods.
For example:

```
$linkData = [
'type'=> "video",
'source'=> "https://mysite/my_file.swf",
'name'=> $_GET['message1'],
'caption'=> $_GET['caption'], 
'description'=> $_GET['message2'],
'message' => $_GET['message3']
];
try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $user->access_token);
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    $this->ueoutputs['errors'][] = $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    $this->ueoutputs['errors'][] = $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
```

it gives me a `Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException`:

> Template data must be a JSON-encoded dictionary, of the form {'key-1': 'value-1', 'key-2': 'value-2', ...}

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is using the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/). 
Here is an example:

```
<meta property="og:audio" content="http://example.com/bond/theme.mp3" />
<meta property="og:description" 
  content="Sean Connery found fame and fortune as the
           suave, sophisticated British agent, James Bond." />
<meta property="og:determiner" content="the" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/bond/trailer.swf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `/me/feed` into `/me/videos`. It works for me.

```
    $response = $fb->post('/me/videos', $linkData, $user->access_token);
```

Comment: I don't want to upload it. Just display it on timeline.

Comment: You mean you want to share the video link in your timeline?

Comment: In anyones timeline. But not just share the link but it would also play on my timeline.

Comment: I guess you are trying to upload it. And whats wrong in uploading the file? That will let you play the video in timeline.

Comment: Because the url of the files is some what like this: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bleupage/app/flash/BleuPageCreative.swf?url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fbleupage%2Fapp%2Fflash%2Fjson%2FVMRGJdZWdH.json&id=Rm34cIy1hQ&logo&logoclickurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bleupage.com` It GET arguments from user.

Comment: First thing: **You cannot upload an swf file in facebook**. Here is the list of supported formates: 3g2, 3gp, 3gpp, asf, avi, dat, divx, dv, f4v, flv, m2ts, m4v, mkv, mod, mov, mp4, mpe, mpeg, mpeg4, mpg, mts, nsv, ogm, ogv, qt, tod, ts, vob, and wmv.

Comment: So you must share a link of the file in the user timeline. If you would like to post a link in users timeline on his behalf, you will need to send your app to the Facebook team for review. If you want that users themselves will share the link, you can just use the facebook share button.

Comment: But if you share the link, users will have to download it to play. So if you want that users will be able to play the video in their timeline, convert the video into any other format, then upload the video to facebook. You can upload video from a download link.See [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads)

Comment: I don't want to upload it. I want to embed it. It is not a video it is a form. It won't work of it is converted. And it is possible to embed a swf file on facebook timeline. I just want to know how to do it.

Comment: I don't think you can "embed" something in facebook!!